# Python question : The output will be method-type. How can I change the method type?

Tags: python-3.x, function, methods

method return type is method. How can I change the method type.
(self.get_sum, self.get_avg)  <--- this is method type...ㅠㅠ

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, korean, math, english): #constructor
        self.name = name
        self.korean = korean
        self.math = math
        self.english = english

    def get_sum(self): #method
        return self.korean + self.math + self.english

    def get_avg(self): #method
        return self.get_sum / 4

    def to_str(self): #method
        return "{}\t{}\t{}".format(self.name, self.get_sum, self.get_avg)

students = [
        Student("a",55,55,55),
        Student("b",54,54,54),
        Student("c",53,53,53),
        Student("c",52,52,52)
]

print("name", "sum", "avg", sep = "\t")
for student in students:
    print(student.to_str())
```

Comment: your not calling the methods your just passing their reference. you should change to `return "{}\t{}\t{}".format(self.name, self.get_sum(), self.get_avg())`

Comment: Let me know how I can change

Comment: I showed you what to change in my comment. You need to call the functions so they return the result, currently your just passing the reference to the functions

Comment: When you call a method, you need parentheses - on line 12 & line 15..

Comment: oh my god ~~thank you very much~~^^

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the functions so they execute and return a result. Currently your only passing a reference to the function not actually executing it. As a side note, your function for average seems to be off, your sum adds 3 values but your average divides by 4.....

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, korean, math, english): #constructor
        self.name = name
        self.korean = korean
        self.math = math
        self.english = english

    def get_sum(self): #method
        return self.korean + self.math + self.english

    def get_avg(self): #method
        #return self.get_sum / 4
        return self.get_sum() / 4

    def to_str(self): #method
        #return "{}\t{}\t{}".format(self.name, self.get_sum, self.get_avg)
        return "{}\t{}\t{}".format(self.name, self.get_sum(), self.get_avg())

students = [
        Student("a",55,55,55),
        Student("b",54,54,54),
        Student("c",53,53,53),
        Student("c",52,52,52)
]

print("name", "sum", "avg", sep = "\t")
for student in students:
    print(student.to_str())
```